# fread unable to read files with double quotes in csv cells

Tags: r, data.table

CSV file looks as follows when opened in text editor

```
answer,context,probability
"Arya Stark,","f Eddard and Catelyn Stark.
* Arya Stark, younger daughter of Eddard an",0.43330684040086
"""Ned"" Stark,"," Night's Watch.
* Lord Eddard ""Ned"" Stark, Warden of the North and Lord ",0.017467418608936747
```

When opened in excel it looks like this :

[image]

Using fread() I am getting the following datatable

```
df = data.table::fread( file.choose() )
```

[image]

Using read.csv() I am facing no such error.

Have looked in the following two links however the solutions provided there does not sole the problem.

[Using fread to read data with double quotes and incorrect escape characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35626797/using-fread-to-read-data-with-double-quotes-and-incorrect-escape-characters)

[Error reading Field with Double Quotes and Commas using Fread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30515673/error-reading-field-with-double-quotes-and-commas-using-fread)

How to solve this ?

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: i believe this is related to known issues such as: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3509